# How did Mark's words about afterlife become public?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invention-of-lying

In **[The Invention of Lying](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1058017/)**, Mark said these words to his dying mom:

> Mark: You're wrong about what happens after you die. It's not an
>   eternity of nothingness.
>
> Mom: huh?
>
> Mark: You go to your favorite place in the whole world.

He said these words in the hospital in presence of doctors. Then how did they become public?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm..  Because the doctors spoke with other people, who then spoke with other people?

Don't forget that in this truthful, honest society, there probably isn't a need for confidentiality - everyone's going to tell each other everything anyway.